# Incorrect display of the menu item

Tags: java, swing

When I add to my `JMenuItem` new Icon or `ImageIcon`, then the text becomes the same color as the icon.

[image: Example Screenshot]

My code:

```
JMenuButton red = new JMenuItem("Red", getIcon(Color.RED));

private Icon getIcon(Color color){
    return new Icon() {

        @Override
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.translate(x,y);
            g2.setPaint(color);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.fillOval( 0, 2, 10, 10 );
            g2.translate(-x,-y);
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return 14;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return 14;
        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
```

Don't just cast the `Graphics` object to a `Graphics2D`.

Any changes you make to the `Graphics2D` object will be retained by the `Graphics` object.

Instead create a separate Graphics object that you can temporarily customize:

```
Graphpics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

//  do custom painting

g2.dispose();
```

Now the changes will only apply to the custom painting code.